# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession when trying to run my app

Tags: ios6

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession   
>Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/13CCBC3E-79B1-482F-ABC8-94D42CBA7F60/MyApp.app/MyApp   
>Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation  in /var/mobile/Applications/13CCBC3E-79B1-482F-ABC8-94D42CBA7F60/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

Getting this error when trying to run myapp. If I made foundation framework optional then its working fine.

When I made the framework required & then try to run the app it crashes with this error in ios6 and working fine in ios7 & 8.

Please help me with the solution as making foundation framework optional slow downs my app.

Comment: have you figured it out? got the same issue